# pySerial: how to check the current baud rate

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have a device ([GT511C3 fingerprint scanner](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/datasheet-sen-11792.pdf)) that I am connecting to Raspberry Pi and programming it using [Python Serial module](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). The GT511 device has a default baud rate of 9600, and there is capability of changing the it. Once you change the GT511 baudrate, it keeps this setting until next restart.

The question is if there is a way for me to check the current baud rate of the connected device (in case the device was already programmed, and connected by a different host). I know it is possible to do it using `stty`:

```
$> stty < /dev/ttyAMA0
speed 57600 bud; line = 0
...
```

Is there a way to do it using Python serial or any other module, or do I have to write an iterative checking procedure to find it out?

**UPDATE 1:**
Current solution I use to find the accepted baud rate:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0')
ser.timeout = 0.5
for baudrate in ser.BAUDRATES:
    if 9600 <= baudrate <= 115200:
        ser.baudrate = baudrate
        ser.write(packet)
        resp = ser.read()
        if resp != '':
            break
if ser.baudrate > 115200:
    raise RuntimeError("Couldn't find appropriate baud rate!")
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Please, stop suggesting `serial.baudrate` - this is **NOT** what I am asking.

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question in update 1. Update 2 doesn't make sense to me...are you looking for answers that do not try to use the pySerial method?

Comment: The `serial.baudrate` is not what I am looking for because it will give me what I already know. I am trying to find out what devices will the remote respond to.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you shoul use `stty` until you find a better alternative.
You can call it from Python code and parse the result to obtain what you need.
Here is a basic example (not tested):

```
import subprocess
import shlex

def get_baudrate(device):
    command = 'stty < {0}'.format(device)
    proc_retval = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(command))
    baudrate = int(proc_retval.split()[1])
    return baudrate
```

Answer (score 2):

Found your question while searching, and this is working great for me:

```
import serial

def baud_rate_test(serial_port, packet = b' '):
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port)
    ser.timeout = 0.5
    for baudrate in ser.BAUDRATES:
        if 300 <= baudrate <= 57600:
            ser.baudrate = baudrate
            ser.write(packet)
            resp = ser.readall()
            if resp == packet:
                return baudrate
    return 'Unknown'

a = baud_rate_test('/dev/ttyUSB1')
print(a)
```

The devices I have checked it with to this point echo back the "b' '" with no issue. I do plan on testing it on more devices as time goes on, and I'm thinking I may need to change the "test packet" and the response criteria.
The resp != '': line didn't work for me -- because different "weird" characters are returned at different baud rates.

Comment: Isn't it literally copy/paste of the solution that I already had in the `UPDATE 1` section?

Comment: Basically, yes. As I noted, I needed to check if the packet was returned (Echoed) correctly instead of just checking that there was no response.  Your update 1 would trigger for incorrect bauds on the devices I am communicating with.

Comment: Should I delete this and instead comment up on the question? Haven't used Stackoverflow much...

Comment: Oh I see what you were trying to do -- you were just having a comment, am I right? Generally, if you are posting by clicking "Answer ...", that implies that you have a solution to the original question beyond an existing workaround. However, it doesn't really matter, but be aware that some people might still downvote your answer because it does not contribute to the overall answer. Don't get offended by it though -- that's just an SO mechanism. For minor comments, you might be better off posting a comment right under the original question :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Geiger counter GMC-300 et al belong to the class of devices, which do NOT respond with anything to an unknown byte! They want to get something they understand.

Comment: What actually is .readall() doing? It is not documented under pyserial and nowhere did I find an explanation. Does it read only the current buffer? Until a specific byte is found? Untile something else happens?